# Convert complex SQL query with many joins to Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a working SQL query graciously gifted to me by a stackoverflow member and it works in Laravel:

```
$actives = DB::select('SELECT a.* ,COALESCE(b.sold,0), sold
                      FROM ( SELECT * FROM products p 
                      WHERE p.product_type_id = 1
                      AND DATE(p.visible_date) <= ? 
                      AND p.active = 1 
                      AND (p.end_date >= ? or p.end_date IS NULL) ) a 
                      LEFT JOIN ( SELECT product_id , SUM(quantity) sold 
                      FROM order_items oi JOIN orders o 
                      ON o.id = oi.order_id 
                      AND o.paid is not null 
                      GROUP BY product_id ) b
                      ON b.product_id = a.id', [Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()]);
```

But this returns an array, and I'm looking for a collection. I can't use `selectRaw` because that method always adds `FROM tablename` at the end of the query.

I've separated a and b into subqueries, both of which work:

```
$a = DB::table('products')
         ->where('product_type_id', 1)
         ->whereDate('visible_date', '<=', Carbon::now())
         ->where('active', true)
         ->where(function ($query) {
             $query->where('end_date', '>=', Carbon::now())
                   ->orWhere('end_date', null);  
                   });

$b = DB::table('order_items')
         ->selectRaw('product_id , SUM(quantity) sold')
         ->join('orders', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_items.order_id')
         ->whereNotNull('orders.paid')
          ->groupBy('product_id');
```

The Eloquent query builder has a `leftJoinSub` function, but the documentation seems to show that it's only good for joining a query with one subquery, whereas I appear to need to join a new query ON two subqueries.

Does anybody know how to put the raw SQL into Eloquent so I'm returned a collection of Products instead of an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler way that will also cost less ressources to your database

I suppose you already declared the relations orders between `Product` and `Order`

```
Class Product extends Model
{
    public function getSoldAttribute()
    {
        return $this->orderItems()
            ->select(\DB::raw('SUM(quantity) as sold'))
            ->join('orders', 'order_items.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
            ->whereNotNull('orders.paid')
            ->groupBy('product_id')
            ->value('sold');
    }
...
```

Then you fetch your products with the filters you want and access the `$product->sold` attribute

```
$products = Products::where('product_type_id', 1)
     ->whereDate('visible_date', '<=', Carbon::now())
     ->where('active', true)
     ->where(function ($query) {
         $query->where('end_date', '>=', Carbon::now())
               ->orWhere('end_date', null);  
     })->get();
foreach($products as $product) {
    var_dump($product->sold);
}
```

you can also force load the `sold` attribute in the `Product` model with `protected $appends = ['sold'];`

Comment: I don't have a relationship between `Product` and `Order`. There's a relationship between `Order` and `OrderItem`, and a relationship between `Product` and `OrderItem`. Should I make a new hasManyThrough?

Comment: This is looking like just what I want, but I'm getting errors. First, I get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::groupBy()`. Another article says to move it before the `select`, which I've done and now I get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::value()`.

Comment: @Jacey did you do `return $this->orders->select(` instead of `return $this->orders()->select(`. Can you add the `orders` relation to you quesiton ?

Comment: I copied it just as you wrote it, which is missing a parenthesis, BTW, but I corrected that. I added the relationship `public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Order', 'App\OrderItem');
    }`

Comment: Yes. It's not actually orders I want either. I want the sum of OrderItems of that product id where Orders.paid is not null.

Comment: @Jacey you just edit the `getSoldAttribute()` method, updated my answer

Comment: @Jacey you OrderItem is a pivot table. `Product` -> `order` relation should be `belongToMany`. check the edit

Comment: order_items is not a pivot table. The correction I posted works. Keep my correction and I'll approve your answer.

Comment: Rolled back to your correction. I get that you are using `OrderItem` as a model, but it's fulfilling a `pivot` role in this context

Comment: It's not a pivot table. Products contains a base price and when a user adds a product to their cart, the code calculates a bunch of scenarios to see if the user should get some sort of discount, and then adds it to the order_items table with the price for that user. So you can't have a pivot for that scenario since the price in the order_items table is not necessarily the base price of the product.

Comment: @Jacey you add order_unit_price in the pivot table. nothing complicated